# Error saving credit card information. Try again later.

Tags: ios-appstore, development

I am trying to join https://searchads.apple.com , but I am getting this error:

> Error saving credit card information. Try again later.  (Error: 3564473453).

I read something about it here and it looks that it is because I am using a debit card. 
**My question is:** Does anyone know what could solve my problem(except using credit card).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the store for the first time with an existing Apple ID, you must provide a payment method. After you create the account, you can change your payment information to "None."
If you're creating a new Apple ID, you might be able to create an account without entering your credit card details.